# Non-navigation NON fixed navbar bottom not stretching full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer, navbar

I am trying to get the bottom navbar which is inverse and non fixed and non navigation to stretch full width to cover the complete viewport...well in terms of the design effect it is to have a nice footer stretching full width non fixed...

it used to work when I was on an navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom role=presentation. I've tried to change div into row, set row before navbar... it is either I loose the full length or either I loose the inverse... each time I'm gaining something I'm loosing something else... Aaarrrggh... I don't know where to look anymore and I don't have enough knowledge to go and mess around with the media attributes... Anyone has a solution? Thanks a bunch... Max

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="presentation">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Partner Companies:</strong><br>                     
        <a href="http://www.monsoon-zanzibar.com">Monsoon Restaurant</a><br>
        <a href="http://www.kasha-zanzibar.com">Kasha Boutique Hotel</a><br>
        <a href="http://www.konokonozanzibar.com">Konokono Beach Villas</a><br>
        <a href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g488129-d1218694-Reviews-Livingstone_Beach_Restaurant-Stone_Town_Zanzibar_Zanzibar_Archipelago.html">Livingstone Restaurant</a><br>
        <a href="http://www.theseyyida-zanzibar.com">Seyyida Hotel & Spa</a></li>
        <span><a class="glyphicon-copyright-mark"></a>Copyright SERENE TOURS ZNZ 2014</span>        
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Office Tanzania:</strong><br>
        Kenyatta Shangani<br>
        P.O. Box 1370<br>
        Stonetown Zanzibar<br>
        +255242234402 Tel<br>
        +244242234411 Fax<br></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>US Office:</strong><br>
        250 Gabriel Circle #9<br>
        Sapphire Lakes<br>
        Naples FL US-34104<br>
        +12393008592 Tel<br>
        +12393528777 Fax<br></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Follow us:</strong><br>
    <a href="http://https://www.youtube.com/user/SereneSafariToursZNZ" rel="publisher"><img src="_images/youtube30x30.jpg"> You Tube</a><br>
    <span id="tumblr_button_abc123"></span><br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/serenesafaris" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/SereneToursZanzibar"><img src="http://www.socialmediabuttons.com/images/facebook6.gif" title=""></a><br>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/serenesafaristourszanzibar?ref=badge"><img src="_images/instagram.jpg" alt="Instagram"> Instagram</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: width looks ok on bootply (http://www.bootply.com/TAKxqqGCSL)

Comment: Well the navbar is short of is not stretching all the way, it looks like a black box plunked at the bottom of the page centered with two empty space of +/- 30px on each side which transpire the background watermark...